# How can I validate nested objects with validate.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, validate.js

I have objects like this that I would like to validate using validate.js:

```
let inventory={
      id:'86366524-9781-4570-ab36-fba5e64d1d27',
      items:[
          {
               type:'sword', 
               power:33,
               amount:1
          },
          {
               type:'coin',
               amount:34
          }
      ],
      owner:{
            name:"batman_32",
            level:33,
            clan:"nightwind"
      }
}
```

To validate the id, I wrote a custom uuid validator. But for the items, I would like to write a validator that is then applied to ever element.
And for the owner I just need a way to validate the nested component.

Is there a way to do this using validate.js with either a custom plugin or by writing some sort of 'drilling' validator?

Or is there a better validation library for things like this?

Comment: I've had a similar problem recently, ended up moving to a different library. Take a look at jsonschema

Comment: looks interesting, thanks